# AttachConsole and QProcess::readAll()

Tags: c++, windows, qt

A user complained that my cmd application flashed a command line window when called in a specific GUI setup.

For his sake I made the application a gui application and attatch to console. Works quite good besides problems with the cursor when calling it from powershell.

The biggest problem is that the output is now no longer catched by the calling Qt apllication (`QProcess::MergedChannels` and `readAll`) because the cmd application directly puts its output to the containing console window instead to the calling Qt application.

Is there a better way than calling `AttachConsole` or should I add a special command line option to the application to prevent the attatch?

EDIT: attatch code https://github.com/Snorenotify/Snoretoast/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L209

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem when working on Inkscape. The best way to have command-line output from a GUI application when it is run in a console, similar to Unix, is to have two executables.

- `program.exe` is a windowed application.
- `program.com` is a helper console application that spawns `program.exe` and pipes console input and output to it. Note that it has nothing to do with COM executables from DOS - it's just a standard PE executable renamed to `.com`.

Since the default order of preference for executable extensions in the `cmd` shell has `.com` before `.exe`, typing `program` in the shell will execute `program.com`, not `program.exe`.

For a working example, see this file:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/trunk/view/head:/src/winconsole.cpp - pasted below for convenience.

```
/**
 * \file
 * Command-line wrapper for Windows.
 *
 * Windows has two types of executables: GUI and console.
 * The GUI executables detach immediately when run from the command
 * prompt (cmd.exe), and whatever you write to standard output
 * disappears into a black hole. Console executables
 * do display standard output and take standard input from the console,
 * but when you run them from the GUI, an extra console window appears.
 * It's possible to hide it, but it still flashes for a fraction
 * of a second.
 *
 * To provide an Unix-like experience, where the application will behave
 * correctly in command line mode and at the same time won't create
 * the ugly console window when run from the GUI, we have to have two
 * executables. The first one, inkscape.exe, is the GUI application.
 * Its entry points are in main.cpp and winmain.cpp. The second one,
 * called inkscape.com, is a small helper application contained in
 * this file. It spawns the GUI application and redirects its output
 * to the console.
 *
 * Note that inkscape.com has nothing to do with "compact executables"
 * from DOS. It's a normal PE executable renamed to .com. The trick
 * is that cmd.exe picks .com over .exe when both are present in PATH,
 * so when you type "inkscape" into the command prompt, inkscape.com
 * gets run. The Windows program loader does not inspect the extension,
 * just like an Unix program loader; it determines the binary format
 * based on the contents of the file.
 *
 *//*
 * Authors:
 *   Jos Hirth <jh@kaioa.com>
 *   Krzysztof Kosinski <tweenk.pl@gmail.com>
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2008-2010 Authors
 *
 * Released under GNU GPL, read the file 'COPYING' for more information
 */

#ifdef WIN32
#undef DATADIR
#include <windows.h>

struct echo_thread_info {
    HANDLE echo_read;
    HANDLE echo_write;
    unsigned buffer_size;
};

// thread function for echoing from one file handle to another
DWORD WINAPI echo_thread(void *info_void)
{
    echo_thread_info *info = static_cast<echo_thread_info*>(info_void);
    char *buffer = reinterpret_cast<char *>(LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, info->buffer_size));
    DWORD bytes_read, bytes_written;

    while(true){
        if (!ReadFile(info->echo_read, buffer, info->buffer_size, &bytes_read, NULL) || bytes_read == 0)
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE)
                break;

        if (!WriteFile(info->echo_write, buffer, bytes_read, &bytes_written, NULL)) {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_DATA)
                break;
        }
    }

    LocalFree(reinterpret_cast<HLOCAL>(buffer));
    CloseHandle(info->echo_read);
    CloseHandle(info->echo_write);

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    // structs that will store information for our I/O threads
    echo_thread_info stdin = {NULL, NULL, 4096};
    echo_thread_info stdout = {NULL, NULL, 4096};
    echo_thread_info stderr = {NULL, NULL, 4096};
    // handles we'll pass to inkscape.exe
    HANDLE inkscape_stdin, inkscape_stdout, inkscape_stderr;
    HANDLE stdin_thread, stdout_thread, stderr_thread;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength=sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor=NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle=TRUE;

    // Determine the path to the Inkscape executable.
    // Do this by looking up the name of this one and redacting the extension to ".exe"
    const int pathbuf = 2048;
    WCHAR *inkscape = reinterpret_cast<WCHAR*>(LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, pathbuf * sizeof(WCHAR)));
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, inkscape, pathbuf);
    WCHAR *dot_index = wcsrchr(inkscape, L'.');
    wcsncpy(dot_index, L".exe", 4);

    // we simply reuse our own command line for inkscape.exe
    // it guarantees perfect behavior w.r.t. quoting
    WCHAR *cmd = GetCommandLineW();

    // set up the pipes and handles
    stdin.echo_read = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    stdout.echo_write = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    stderr.echo_write = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    CreatePipe(&inkscape_stdin, &stdin.echo_write, &sa, 0);
    CreatePipe(&stdout.echo_read, &inkscape_stdout, &sa, 0);
    CreatePipe(&stderr.echo_read, &inkscape_stderr, &sa, 0);

    // fill in standard IO handles to be used by the process
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFOW si;

    ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdInput = inkscape_stdin;
    si.hStdOutput = inkscape_stdout;
    si.hStdError = inkscape_stderr;

    // spawn inkscape.exe
    CreateProcessW(inkscape, // path to inkscape.exe
                   cmd, // command line as a single string
                   NULL, // process security attributes - unused
                   NULL, // thread security attributes - unused
                   TRUE, // inherit handles
                   0, // flags
                   NULL, // environment - NULL = inherit from us
                   NULL, // working directory - NULL = inherit ours
                   &si, // startup info - see above
                   &pi); // information about the created process - unused

    // clean up a bit
    LocalFree(reinterpret_cast<HLOCAL>(inkscape));
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(inkscape_stdin);
    CloseHandle(inkscape_stdout);
    CloseHandle(inkscape_stderr);

    // create IO echo threads
    DWORD unused;
    stdin_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, echo_thread, (void*) &stdin, 0, &unused);
    stdout_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, echo_thread, (void*) &stdout, 0, &unused);
    stderr_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, echo_thread, (void*) &stderr, 0, &unused);

    // wait until the standard output thread terminates
    WaitForSingleObject(stdout_thread, INFINITE);

    return 0;
}

#endif
```

To summarize: the helper application creates three pipes. It spawns the windowed application using `CreateProcess`, giving it the appropriate ends of the pipes as standard input, output and error handles. Finally, it creates three threads that copy the data from the pipes to the standard input, output and error of the helper application.

Comment: This is a brilliant hack. I love it.

Comment: Hm thats what I was doing with https://github.com/TheOneRing/vsd (but there also for the debug stream) but I think I would rather compile two versions ( a cmd version and a GUI version)  as this would still be much cleaner. The intention of the `AttachConsole` code was to avoid the need of two versions.

Comment: @TheOneRing How is providing two big files with 99% identical content better for the user ("cleaner") than just one of the big files, and an additional file that is very small?

Comment: As you can use dlls your application can be quite small. From my experience with `CreateProcessW` I know redirecting output using threads isn't that simple too.

Comment: About the only optimization I see would be to use just one worker thread - the data copying will be memory-bound and there's little point to wasting three threads' worth of stack pages just to shuffle these little buffers around between pipes.